# No me funciona el Router en PHP

Tags: php, router

me salen los siguientes errores a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación[image: Errores]

Ya he intentado de muchas maneras pero no me funciona ¿Qué solución me darías? Adjunto el código.

router.php

```
<?php
include_once "models/DB.php";
include_once "models/Tarea.php";

$controller = $_GET['controller'];
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if (empty($action))
    $action = "index";

$ctrlName = $controller . "Controller";
include "./controllers/$ctrlName.php";
$ctrl = new $ctrlName;
$ctrl->{$action}();

//var_dump($_GET);
```

TareasControllers.php

```
<?php

class TareasController {
    public function index() {
        //$tareas = Tarea::all();
        //var_dump($tareas);

        //$tarea = Tarea::find(1);
        //var_dump($tarea);
    }

    public function create(){
        echo "Estamos en create";
    }


    // index  - Lista todos los elementos
    // show   - Mostrar un elemento específico por id
    // create - Crear un elemento
    // update - Editar un elemento
    // delete - Borrar un elemento

}
```

Tarea.php

```
<?php
class Tarea extends DB
{
    public $id;
    public $nombre;
    public $vencimiento;

    public static function all()
    {
        $db = new DB();
        $prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tareas");
        $prepare->execute();

        return $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Tarea::class);
    }
    public function save()
    {
        $params = [":nombre" => $this->nombre, ":vencimiento" => $this->vencimiento];
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            $prepare = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO tareas(nombre, vencimiento) VALUES (:nombre, :vencimiento)");
            $prepare->execute($params);
        } else {
            $params[":id"] = $this->id;
            $prepare = $this->prepare("UPDATE tareas SET nombre=:nombre, vencimiento=:vencimiento WHERE id=:id");
            $prepare->execute($params);
        }
    }
    public function remove()
    {
        $prepare = $this->prepare("DELETE FROM tareas WHERE id=:id");
        $prepare->execute([":id" => $this->id]);
    }
}
```

A continuación la organización de las carpetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para solucionar los errores anteriormente mencionado, cabe aclarar que soy nuevo en el lenguaje PHP y he tenido un poco de complicaciones respecto al tema de importar y utilizar código, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta con `include "./controllers/".$ctrlName.".php";`, además, recibes `TareasController` en tu parámetro, y tu archivo se llama `TareasControllers`...

Answer (score 0):

```
include __DIR__ . "/controllers/$ctrlName.php";
```

reemplaza la linea de inclusion en router.php con eso.

o podrias actualizar con set_include_path el path y agregar la rais de tu proecto para que la linea que tiene sde include funciona sin mas.

```
$ruta = '/path/detu/proyecto';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $ruta);
```